# $X$ is regular iff $Y$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $q:X\to Y$ be a quotient function (i,e $q$ is continuous, onto and $U\subseteq Y$ is open iff $q^{-1}(U)$ is open). I need to show that $X$ is a regular topological space iff $Y$ is regular too.

I don't know how attack my problem. I tried to use the quotient space over $X$ generated by the partition $\{q^{-1}(y):y\in Y\}$ which is homeomorphic to $Y$ but I didn't get nothing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am pretty certain that $X$ and $Y$ are meant to be just topological spaces, but if you could confirm that, it would be nice.

Comment: Better explain the context. I have some knowledge in topology but I don't know what a "quotient function" is...

Comment: @JeanMarie see my edit.

Comment: @Arthur yes, $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quotient space of a regular space  need not be regular. Let $X=\Bbb R$
and $\sim$ be the equivalence on it with $x\sim y$ if $x=y=0$ or if $xy\ne0$.
Then $Y=X/\sim$ has two points (one closed, the other not), but is not regular.

Comment: The partition is generated by a quotient map. In this context is my question.

Comment: In my example, $\pi:X\to Y$ is a quotient map, $X$ is regular, $Y$ is not. @Gödel

Comment: I see it, thanks